# C++ function pointer's address invariance

Tags: c++, compilation, pointer-to-member

I know that function pointers` addresses do not change among various compilation units.

```
struct Interface
{
   void sum(int, int);
};
```

For instnce, `&Interface::sum` will yield the same value among different units (Am I wrong?).

1. At what extent does this hold? Will the address be the same when compiled on a different machine, system?
2. Can a function address be a reliable tool to use in a public header? For example, to use it for internal mapping or tag dispatching.

I suspect it might be different when a different compiler is used.

I ask this assuming that we have the same size for a function pointer (i.e. for x64).

Comment: the address also depend on the order you link files. Note `sum` is not a function, if you want it to be a function declare it `friend`. What is your real need ? That seems to be a xy problem

Comment: @bruno it is a member function. Are there any issues to consider with a member function pointer as with just a function pointer? My real need here is stated in my question. I am curious to know about the behaviour of function addresses and their potential use.

Comment: *there any issues to consider with a member function pointer as with just a function pointer?* you cannot call `sum` as a (C) function, it must be applied to an instance of `Interface` or an instance of an inheriting class

Comment: @bruno I am competely aware of that. But still, a member function has its own address. And my question as regarding its address behaviour. Not the way it is supposed to be called.

Comment: out of the scope of your question, if you want to have *Interface* a real interface do `virtual void sum(int, int) =0;` supposing it is not defined for `Interface`

Comment: yes a member function has its own address, it is constant and unique during an execution but you cannot suppose more, exactly like for a function

Comment: `&Interface::sum` is a **pointer-to-member-function**. It is **not** a function pointer. It will typically contain extra data to handle things like virtualness and derived-base conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would like to emphasize that the fact that `sum` is a method is unrelated to the answer.

Second, the address will be the same across all compilation units because it's the most efficient - otherwise, you have to duplicate `sum` in the executable. If it's in only once place, every caller can just `call` there.

Third, the address might not be the same even if you rerun the program. It probably will, if the executable loads to the same *base address*, but there's no guarantee. Therefore, the address also isn't guaranteed to be the same on a different machine/system, and isn't a reliable tool to use in a header file.

Last, a different compiler, or even using the same compiler after slightly changing the code, may place `sum` in a different location in your executable, so your final suspicion was correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the Last part, in my experience, changing the code in a compilation unit did not affect the address. Even adding or removing methods didn't change the address of an existing functions.

Comment: You can try adding a function in the same compilation unit before `sum`. That should "push it forward" a bit.

Comment: On the contrary: the fact that `sum` is a member function is **critical** to the answer. `&Interface::sum` is **not** a function pointer. It's a **pointer-to-member-function**, and you cannot assume that it holds only a memory address; in fact it's much more complex than that. This answer is correct for a **function pointer**, i.e., `void func(int, int)` outside any class.

Comment: You are wrong, I encourage you to test it yourself - function methods still have a single instance in memory, and the "this" argument is passed as a hidden "first parameter".

Comment: @PeteBecker regarding the addresses the answer is ok. I know, that pointer to member function presumably holds a flag to show if it is virtual. But you can post an aswer on what adds up to member pointer address and I will upvote it.

Comment: @NadavS -- yes, each **function** has a single address. That doesn't mean that there is anything meaningful you can do with a **pointer to member function**. You don't know what's inside it. For a virtual function it could, for example, just be a flag and an offset into a vtable, with no memory address. `&Interface::sum`, despite being called a "pointer to member function", is **not** an ordinary pointer.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik -- there is no language-level mechanism for getting the memory address of a member function.

Comment: @PeteBecker what do you mean? `&Interface::sum` will yield an address. Can you clarify?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik -- again: `&Interface::sum` yields a "pointer-to-member-function" which, despite the name, is **not** a pointer. It's whatever the compiler needs in order to call that member function through the "pointer-to-member-function", and you don't know what's inside it. In some situations it could be an address, but in others it might not be. For example, calling a virtual function (with the usual implementation) requires **only** an offset into the vtable. No pointer. (Yes, the vtable has a pointer, but you don't have information about the vtable in the pointer-to-member-function).

Comment: pointer to a member function does not hold any flag. Pointer to a class instance may actually be a pointer to a vtable of functions/classes, but it's unrelated. `&Interface::sum` indeed yields the correct address, and you can use it to call the member function with some gimmicky syntax, **even when marked virtual** (I can demonstrate).  I again urge you to test it yourself instead of posting more comments.

Comment: You can read first google search result instead https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @PeteBecker how is it not a pointer? Yes, it does not act like a usual pointer or pointer to a function, but for a non-virtual member function it has an address. And with a workaround it can actually be cast to a usual pointer (despite being considered a UB). 
`auto pSum = &Interface::sum; // pointer-to-member-function`
`void(**ppSum)(void*, int, int) = (void(**)(void*, int, int))&pSum;  // usual pointer to function pointer`
`(**ppSum)(nullptr, 13, 16);  // outputs 29`

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik -- yes, you've found a particular situation where a pointer-to-member-function can be treated as if it was an ordinary pointer. That does not mean that a pointer-to-member-function is always an ordinary pointer. Try it with a virtual function.

Comment: @PeteBecker with a virtual function you will need to provide a pointer to an existing object first. I think the problem is in miscommunication. I say it is a pointer, but not the same as a regular pointer (still yields an address). You say it is not a pointer (still may yield an address). I never said it is the same as a function pointer (though can be cast to). My question was about the immutability of the resulting address.

Comment: To sum up on what (I think) we can all agree on, `Interface::sum` in the code snippet above should yield a pointer to a function. Marking it as `virtual`, for instance, should cause it to yield something else, I do not know if some standard specifies what or it's up to the compiler. In any case, the yielded value can be used in a CPP program to work with the method.

Comment: @NadavS -- there is nothing that requires `&Interace::som` to yield a pointer to a function. Keep in mind that a pointer-to-member-function has to handle **any** member function with the correct argument types and return type; that includes non-virtual **and** virtual functions. Back in the olden days, Microsoft's compiler created different pointer-to-member-function types, depending on whether the function was virtual or not, and it was simply a disaster. You could not write reliable code using that stuff, and you had to tell the compiler to **always** generate the more complex data types.